# combine JavaScripts with Laravel-Mix

Tags: jquery, laravel, webpack

I want to use [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/).
When I use its script in the normal way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
```

it works. 
But the weird problem is that when I combine its script with my other scripts (`with Laravel-Mix`), it doesn't work!
**The console error:**
[image: screenshot]
Here is my code:

> webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').version();
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version();
```

> app.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./files/jquery-3.2.1.min')
require('./files/bootstrap');
require('./files/owl.carousel.min');
require('./files/tooltipster.bundle');
```

> and for calling the library:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tooltipster').tooltipster({
            theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
            animation: 'fade'
        });
    });
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I haven't looked at the library but it's common for these older jQuery UMD modules to declare themselves in a closure accepting the `window` and `jquery` as 2nd arguments, so try `require('./files/tooltipster.bundle')(window.$)`

Comment: Thank you @Ohgodwhy, but it didn't work.

Comment: you can put it in your webpack mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js', your_other_script.js], 'public/js').version();

Comment: Thanks @Ikong, but had no effect.